# Coupon Bond Calculator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance

I'm trying to do coupon bond calculations and keep running into "Type Error must be str, not int" in the below code. I cannot figure out where to make it a string.

```
"""The equation is the (sum from j to n of (c/(1+i)^j))+ (f/(1+i)^n)"""

print('What Are You Trying To Solve For?')
startvariable = str(input(' Price (p), Face (f), Years to Maturity (n), Interest Rate (i), Current Yield (cy), YTM (Y)' ).lower() )
while startvariable == 'p':
    f = (input("Face or Par Value (number only): "))
    i = (input("Interest Rate (as decimal): "))
    c = (input("Coupon (number only): "))
    n = (input("n value:  "))
    j = (input("j (starting) value:  "))
    summation_value = 0

    while j <= n:
        for k in range (j, (n + 1)):
            add_me = (c/(1+i)** j)
            summation_value += add_me
            k += 1
        print('Bond Price: ', (summation_value + ((f) / (1 + i) ** n)))
```

Comment: Check the type of variables received from the input function.

Comment: `input` returns a string -- this is defined in the documentation and tutorials.  You try to do computations on a string; I get a couple of different errors -- including the missing rparen on your first input line -- but not the one you cite.  In any case, you need to cast your input values from `str` to `int` and `float`, as needed.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` returns a string -- this is defined in the documentation and tutorials. You try to do computations on a string; I get a couple of different errors -- including the missing rparen on your first `input` line -- but not the one you cite. In any case, you need to cast your input values from `str` to `int` and `float`, as needed

Egbert has them almost correct; the dollar amounts should be floats:

```
f = float(input("Face or Par Value (number only): "))
i = float(input("Interest Rate (as decimal): "))
c = int(input("Coupon (number only): "))
n = int(input("n value: "))
j = int(input("j (starting) value:  "))
```

*After* this, you need to fix the curious infinite loop you built:

```
while j <= n:
```

Since `j` and `n` never change within this loop, it's infinite once you enter.  Most of all, it appears that the `for` loop immediately after is intended to perform the same iteration.

Remove the `while` altogether; I think what I'm  seeing after that change is the correct result.

Comment: Thank you! that is exactly what I needed to do!

Answer (score 0):

```
print('What Are You Trying To Solve For?')
startvariable = str(input(' Price (p), Face (f), Years to Maturity (n), Interest Rate (i), Current Yield (cy), YTM (Y)' ).lower())
while startvariable == 'p':
    f = int(input("Face or Par Value (number only): "))
    i = float(input("Interest Rate (as decimal): "))
    c = int(input("Coupon (number only): "))
    n = int(input("n value: "))
    j = int(input("j (starting) value:  "))
    summation_value = 0

    while j <= n:
        for k in range (j,(n+1)):
            add_me = (c/(1+i)** j)
            summation_value += add_me
            k += 1
        print('Bond Price: ', (summation_value + ((f) / (1 + i) ** n)))
```

Type casting each input to a specific data type made the code run for me. Although am no financial expert to know what the numbers mean or whether they are right. But it no longer printed out the error you mentioned.